# Error al traer una fila de la base de datos (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Tengo el siguiente método para validar si un empleado existe en la base de datos:

```
public void validarEmisor(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id.Equals(Guid.Empty) || id.Equals(null))
                throw new TicketEmisorException("El identificador del ticket emisor no fué provisto");
            IQueryable<Empleado> emisor = _dataContext.Empleado.Where(empleado => empleado.Id == id);
            if (!emisor.Any())
                throw new TicketEmisorException("El emisor indicado no se encuentra registrado en la Base de Datos");
        }
```

Y a pesar de que el empleado existe dentro de la base de datos, el método siempre entra en el TicketPrioridadException.

Esta es mi clase Empleado, la cual hereda de Usuario:

```
public class Empleado : Usuario
    {
        public List<Ticket> Lista_Ticket { get; set; }
        public Cargo Cargo { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Votos_Ticket> Votos_Ticket { get; set; }
    
    }
public abstract class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int cedula { get; set; }
        [Required,MaxLength(50),MinLength(3)]
        public string primer_nombre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required,MaxLength(50),MinLength(3)]
        public string segundo_nombre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required,MaxLength(50),MinLength(3)]
        public string primer_apellido { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(50),MinLength(3)]
        public string segundo_apellido { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        public DateTime fecha_nacimiento { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public char gender { get; set; }
        [Required,DataType(DataType.EmailAddress),EmailAddress]
        public string correo { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required,DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        public DateTime fecha_creacion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime fecha_ultima_edicion { get; set; }
        public DateTime fecha_eliminacion { get; set; }
        public List<Ticket> lista_tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

No entiendo por qué siempre entra en la excepción cuando el empleado existe.

Comment: Imagino que tu problema está en la primera excepción. En tiempo de depuración, ¿tu variable id es null? Por lo que veo no estás recibiendo el id y por lo tanto no realiza la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías implementar tu código así:

```
public bool validarEmisor(Guid? id)
{
    return _dataContext.Empleado.Any(empleado => empleado.Id == id);            
}
```

Luego, con el método ***Any*** de **LINQ** verificas si existe o no el código que buscas, si retorna ***false*** no es válido.

No veo necesario manejar excepciones aquí pues sólo necesitas validar si existe o no el emisor.

Comment: muchas gracias, el problema era porque en los inserts de usuario no se le había pasado el discriminante que le indicara que era de tipo empleado